# Repetition of function call

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pi = np.pi


def draw_first():
    x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.1)
    y = x**3 - 3*x
    plt.plot(x, y)


def draw_second():
    x = np.arange(0, 2*pi, 0.1)
    y = 3*x*np.cos(2*x)
    plt.plot(x, y)


def draw_third():
    x = np.arange(-8*pi, 8*pi, 0.1)
    y = np.sin(x) / x
    plt.plot(x, y)


switch = {
    "1": draw_first,
    "2": draw_second,
    "3": draw_third
}

while True:
    try:
        choice = input("Enter a number [1-3]: ")
        function_called = switch[choice]()
        break
    except:
        print("Try again!")

plt.show()
```

Is there a way not to repeat **plt.plot(x,y)** in every function? I was thinking about something like plt.plot(function_called.x,function_called.y), but i don't think that's right

Comment: Have all the functions return their `x` and `y`, and use: func_x, func_y = switch[choice](). Then after that, use plt.plot(func_x, func_y)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have each function return the `x, y` then call `plt.plot(x, y)` in the caller:

```
def draw_first():
    x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.1)
    y = x**3 - 3*x
    return x, y
```

and then

```
        x, y = switch[choice]()
        plt.plot(x, y)
```

Note that the two pairs of `x, y` are completely separate variables that just happen to have the same names; you could use a different name in each place:

```
        a, b = switch[choice]()
        plt.plot(a, b)
```

Answer (score 3):

`function_called` is `None` here:

```py
function_called = switch[choice]()
```

But you could return `x` and `y` from functions and plot them in the loop:

```py
def draw_first():
    x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.1)
    y = x**3 - 3*x
    return x, y

...

while True:
    try:
        choice = input("Enter a number [1-3]: ")
        x, y = switch[choice]()
        plt.plot(x, y)
    except:
        print("Try again!")

plt.show()
```